# How to detect if a browser can play multiple sounds at the same time

Tags: javascript, html, mobile-safari, html5-audio

Mobile Safari on iOS won't play more than one HTML5 audio file at the same time. I've been using the following to check if multiple sounds can be played:

```
var isIos = /iPhone|iPad|iPod/i.test( navigator.userAgent );
```

I would prefer checking for feature support directly instead of testing for individual platforms. There's always a (small) chance that the feature will be added to Safari later, and there might be other browsers that have the same limitation and won't be detected with this code.

Is there a more reliable way to check or test whether multiple concurrent sounds are supported?

Comment: Mobile Safari IOS6 will play multiple sounds.  This example isn't mobile optomized, but it plays multiple sounds over each other.  It's from an old experiment of mine.  http://www.matthewtoledo.com/   just tap on a few letters and you'll hear multiple bounce sounds played over each-other

Comment: @mrbinky3000 while that is a fun bit of JavaScript, I have to point out that there's a typo: `watch you're computer struggle!`